# How to make a div in a webpage 'selectable' by Safari Web Clip?

Tags: mac, html, safari

On some websites, when you try to create a webclipping in Safari for use in Dashboard, the selection "snaps" to divs on the page. (E.g., superuser.com)

On other sites, you have to manually adjust the selection, resulting in a less accurate clip.

How do enable the div-snapping action in HTML?

[Here is a screengrab](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bk9288oytbej3oz/snap.mov?dl=0) of a site that does "snap". You can see how the rectangle snaps to certain DIVs.

[Here is one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mhztd0c4s0byvxx/nosnap.mov?dl=0) that does not. You have to manually adjust the size.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean with "div-snapping". Does this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117620/how-to-make-a-div-snapping-to-a-grid-via-css) help?

Comment: Thanks but no, that's not what I mean at all. I'm specifically talking about the web clip function in Safari, that puts portions of websites on your Dashboard. Maybe better to ask on the Apple site.

Comment: Added screengrabs above

Comment: I don't appear to have that option on my Mac, is it a 3rd party extension?

Comment: No, it's part of Safari, has been for years. If you don't have the button, just go "File > Open in Dashboard..."